# I need another dropdown for AM/PM in datetimepicker

Tags: jquery

I have a datetimepicker which consists of hours and minutes dropdown. Hour drop down is in format{0am,1am,2am,...11am,12pm,1pm,..11pm}. Instead I need a drop down for 1-12 and am/pm as dropdown

Answer (score 0):

On this github there is a datepicker that you maybe want.
http://ericjgagnon.github.io/wickedpicker/
Can't help you more because we have no information of what you already have.